# Footer floats if the page goes beyond normal height

Tags: html, css, flexbox, footer

I am getting the effect below. The blue line is the footer. When the DIV above the footer extends in height the footer floats and doesn't extend to the bottom of the screen.

[image]

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
  height: 100%;
}

.all_content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #0082bb;
}

.home_body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
  background: #f0f0f0;
  align: center;
}

.footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #0082bb;
}
```

```html
<div class="all_content">

  <!-- header -->
  <div class="header"></div>

  <!-- home body -->
  <div class="home_body" align="center"></div>

  <!-- Footer -->
  <div class="footer"></div>

</div>
```

The reason I'm using `flex-grow` for the middle DIV is to ensure the footer is at the bottom of the window even when there isn't much content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not seeing the floating effect you're describing in your layout.

But here's a cleaner version of your code. Hopefully, it helps.

```css
.all_content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}

.header {
  flex: 0 0 80px; /* flex-grow, flex-shrink, flex-basis */
  background: #0082bb;
}

.home_body {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background: #f0f0f0;
  overflow: auto;
}

.home_body > article {
  height: 2000px;
}

.footer {
  flex: 0 0 50px;
  background: #0082bb;
}

body,
html {
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="all_content">
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="home_body">
    <article></article>
  </div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```